# How to inject and render the component in template?

Tags: angular

I iterate block in loop, which one way is more properly to use?

1.

```
<div *ngFor="let block of block">
    <app-posts *ngif="block.type == 'posts'"></app-posts>
</div>
```

2. 

```
<div *ngFor="let block of block">
    <ng-container *ngif="block.type == 'posts'">
      <app-posts></app-posts>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

3. 

```
<div *ngFor="let block of block">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="postComponent" *ngif="block.type == 'posts'">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

4. Create a component dynamically in the logic controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 are basically the same thing. Since 1 is a simpler syntax it would be better.

3 means that you use move the UI and logic for app-posts in to the parent component. In that case calling the template "postComponent" would be confusing since it's a template not a component. Except for very simple cases, I recommend against it.

If you want to have a separate component type for different block.type it can help rather than having a lot of *ngIfs in the HTML.

So I would go for option 1 for simple cases. Or 4 for case when you have many block.types and different component to use for each type.

Edit:

I created a [StackBlitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4nt89n) to demonstrate how you would approad option 4

You defined post types here (in blocks.service.ts in the sample). You add one entry for each block type with the corresponding component type

```
const BlockComponentsTypes = {
    posts : PostsComponent,
    other : OtherComponent,
}
```

Also note in app.module.ts I added all component types that are created dynamically to entryComponents

```
entryComponents: [
    PostsComponent,
    OtherComponent,
],
```

The BlockHostDirective is applied to the divs

```
<div *ngFor="let block of blocks" [appBlockHost]="block">
</div>
```

The when the block property of the directive changes (ngOnChanges), it will call the BlocksService.getComponentFactory. The factory is used to dynamically create the component. Then after the component is created, the block property is initialized.

Note also that I made both PostsComponent  and OtherComponent implement an interface that has a block property.

Comment: Could you extend  about 4 option, what do you mean?

Comment: I have a lot of block types. How it should look?

Comment: I updated by original answer to include a stackblitz sample with how it should look.