# How to clone component?

Tags: angular

I have an component in template:

```
<app-post></app-post>
```

How to clone it by click event and insert it to the last position?

The cloned component should work as an independent component.

Comment: you can use ngFor for that. For example, have an array, and add the new item into that when the click event will work. if you need an example, let me know.

Comment: Pretty easy actually. Init an array in your component and add an *ngFor to that component looping through that array. Add a button with a click that calls a method that pushes and additional item in the array and Angular will do the rest.

Comment: You just beat me to it Ashot 

Comment: @ashot, could you share an example?

Comment: @MikeOne I just wrote fewer characters:)

Comment: Indeed. Will you make this an answer?

Comment: @MikeOne If you want to make an answer, let's go. I will vote up your answer :)

Comment: Thanks man, but on mobile at the moment so it’s a bit too hard to format correctly..

Comment: @Jony what you want to see? I see in this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384992/how-to-inject-and-render-the-component-in-template) you did almost the same thing. just you need to add the new block in the `block` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Use a loop:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <app-post [post]="post"></app-post>
</ng-container
```

2- in your PostComponent, add a "post" attribute in order to be able to access current post object that has been passed.

And basicaly, that's it.